# Openstack: floating ip pool per tenant in neutron

Tags: openstack-neutron

On our platform, we have created two neutron external network with two different subnets.

Is it possible to make a floating ip pool not visible from all tenants ?

Comment: With Mitaka, it is now possible to make external networks only visible to certain tenants, with RBAC rules: http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/networking-guide/config-rbac.html